# Let f: S $\rightarrow$ T and g: T $\rightarrow$ S be two function. If gf is invertible, prove that f is one-to-one and g is onto.

Tags: abstract-algebra, functions, proof-writing

I have tried doing this since the past 2 hours. How do I do this?

Comment: Hint: for one-to-one, try contradiction. Suppose $f$ is NOT one-to-one, and that there are some $x \neq y$ so that $f(x) = f(y)$. Then what can you say? Why does this contradict the assumption that $gf$ is invertible?

Comment: Hint: also try contradiction for onto. Suppose $g$ is NOT onto. Then there is some $s \in S$ which is NOT in the image of $g$. Why is this bad? What does this tell you about $gf$?

Answer (score 0):

It's just a straightforward application of the definitions:

$\bullet \,$If $gf$ is injective, then $f$ is injective because $f(a)=f(b)\Rightarrow gf(a)=gf(b)\Rightarrow a=b$.

$\bullet \,$If $gf$ is surjective, then $g$ is surjective because $b\in S\Rightarrow \exists \,a\in S$ such that $gf(a)=b$, so $f(a)\in T$ gets sent to $b$ by $g$.